# jQuery datepicker is not working for my website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

My website is a WordPress website. I inserted jQuery date picker to my checkout form using WooCommerce checkout field editor plugin, but it didn't work. Because of this I inserted datepicker by manually using jQuery and jQuery-ui. This also didn't worked. I tried a lot to fix this issue, but I still cannot find why it is not working.  Here is my code for datepicker:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//if(!Modernizr.inputtypes.date){ 

jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq( "#shipping_datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});

//}; 
</script>
```

I copied this in a normal php file and try to run it. It worked fine.

My web site is :  http://somi.is/veislubakkar/
to go to the checkout page please visit there and click on *SETJA Í KÖRFU* which is under a product. Then go to http://somi.is/fragangur/.

Comment: How about using `jQuery` instead of `jq`? I may be wrong but debugger shows that `jq` is not defined.

Comment: I've visited your site. It seems that datepicker element gets appended to your dom, but isn't visible due to his css `z-index` value.

Comment: I changed jq to jQuery and comment var jq = jQuery.noConflict();. Still not working.

Comment: Hello Andreivictor, How can I change it? I appreciate your help.

Comment: add this to your css: `.ui-datepicker{z-index:9999 !important;}`. It's not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: Hello andreivictor, Thanks a lot. It worked for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

All I done is to copy your code to jsFiddle, and add some external resoruces you just specify.
And the code looks to work fine. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Hpy8k/

The only change I made was at the following. I add http: at your href="". So now is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Thanks all, for helping me to fix this issue. It's working fine now.